# Hidding the footer on first or last page keep footer space

Tags: ssrs-2008

Hidding the footer on first or last page keep footer space 
If you hide the  footer on the first or last page, SSRS keep the space for the header but it hide the content.how can i use this space because it effecting my design(some records of table are viewed separately in next page)

thanks in advance

Comment: You may need to adjust the margins of the report, you can check the link given below in the Answer

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you hide the **Header/Footer** the space will be available for you to use 

Usually in **Report Properties** you can set the margins top,bottom to suit your requirements, 
and it may be that [Report Body](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255278.aspx) and margins need some adjustment. 

If all your report elements are within the limits `[Width, Height]` of **`Report Body`** then your report should render fine.